# How use operator IN sql on cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

I have a simple problem and I haven't found an answer. I need to do a query with IN operator from MySql.

I've tried to use this sintax:

```
$this->Client->find("all",array("conditions"=>
                              array("ClientRelCelula.rec_cel_codigo IN"=>$celula)
```

but the condition WHERE is so

```
 WHERE `ClientRelCelula`.`rec_cel_codigo` IN = ('2')
```

I found the error, when i retreat the equal ( = ) the query works fine.

Thank you!

Comment: When you use in you don't use the = .

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the `IN` in the condition. If the passed data is an array, Cake will make it an `IN`

For instance:

```
$celula = 2;
$this->Client->find("all",array("conditions"=>
                          array("ClientRelCelula.rec_cel_codigo"=>$celula);
```

Will Produce:

```
WHERE `ClientRelCelula`.`rec_cel_codigo` = 2
```

And this:

```
$celula = array(2, 3, 4);
$this->Client->find("all",array("conditions"=>
                          array("ClientRelCelula.rec_cel_codigo"=>$celula);
```

Will Produce:

```
WHERE `ClientRelCelula`.`rec_cel_codigo` IN (2,3,4)
```